# batch file to keep one of ten lines

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a file with n lines. (n above 100 millions)

I want to output a file with only 1 of 10 lines, I can't split the file in ten part and keep only one part, as it must be a little more random. later I have to do a statistical analysis I can't afford to create a strong bias in the data).

I was thinking of reading the file and for each record if the record number mod 10 then output it.

The constraints are:

- it's a windows (likely hardened) computer possibly XP Vista or Windows server 2003.
- no development tools available
- no network,usb,cd-rom. read no external communication.

Therefore I was thinking of windows batch file (I can't assume powershell, and vbscript is likely to have been removed). And at the moment looking at the FOR /F command.
Still I am not an expert and I don't know how to achieve this.

*Thank you Paul for your answer.
I reformat (with Hosam help) the answer to put it in a batch file:*

```
@echo off
setlocal   
findstr/N . inputFile| findstr ^[0-9]*0: >temporaryFile
FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=: " %%i in (temporaryfile) do echo %%j > outputFile
```

*Thanks quux and Pax for the similar alternative solution. However after a quick test on a larger file Paul's answer is roughly 8 times faster. I guess the evaluation (in SET) is kind of slow, even if the logic seems brilliant.*

Comment: What kind of constraints are those? You can't do professional work under those kinds of constraints. Sounds suspect to me.

Comment: That'll teach me to re-type it instead of cut-and-pasting what worked :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I think I've cracked it:

```
findstr/N . path-to-log-file | findstr ^[0-9]*0:
```

(use findstr to add the line number to the beginning of the line, then again to print only lines with a line number ending in zero)

So you'll get one line in 10, but with the linenumber and colon prepended to each line

<strike>If I can think of a way using command-line tools only of stripping that out, I'll edit this answer :)</strike>

Remove the line number and colon with

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2* delims=: " %i in (file-with-linenumbers) do echo %j
```

Paul.

Comment: two quick things : @ before the echo to output just the data, and the tokens is 1,*. apart from that it's great, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little command script which does what you want (print out every 10 lines of the file lines32.txt exactly). That file (for my tests) held the number 1 through 32 inclusive, one per line, and the output was 10, 20, 30.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /a "n = 0"
for /f %%i in (lines32.txt) do call :fn %%i
endlocal
goto :eof

:fn
set /a "n = n + 1"
if not %n%==10 goto :eof
echo %1
set /a "n = 0"
goto :eof
```

The Windows command language has come quite a way since the bad old DOS days.  I still don't thonk it's a match for ksh or bash but it does a decent job.

Comment: with 2 changes, it works also if there are spaces in the lines; 
    ... call :fn "%%i"
and 
    echo %~1

Answer (score 1):

Paul has a really good answer. By adding the redirection operator you can have the data written to a file.

```
findstr /n . yourLogFile.txt | findstr ^[0-9]*0: > numberedFile.txt
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %i in (numberedFile.txt) do echo %j > smallFile.txt
del numberedFile.txt
```

This will work if run from the command line. If you want to put it in a batch file, replace every '%' character with '%%' (so that %i will become %%i, and %j will be %%j, because in batch files '%' has a special meaning).

Answer (score 1):

The chosen answer might take a very long time to process, since it has to process the whole file twice. If that file is millions of lines ... woosh.

Here's what I came up with. It will simply plod along processing the file sequentially, print each 10th line (ending in whichever digit you like):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET lastdigit=7
SET linecounter=0
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN (text.txt) DO CALL :picker %%a
ENDLOCAL
GOTO :eof

:picker
set line=%*
IF {%linecounter:~-1%} == {%lastdigit%} ECHO %linecounter% %line%
SET /a linecounter=%linecounter% + 1
GOTO :eof
```

Every line is numbered, starting at zero. Any line whose %linenumber% ends in %lastdigit% is echo'd to console, along with the linenumber. Use set /? to see how I came up with that
{%linecounter:~-1%} thing (which simply strips all but the last digit of linenumber).

Comment: Thanks for the valid answer, however the chosen answer seems to be faster.