# Deleting every 2nd line from a file using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am looking for some regex help.

I have a textfile, nothing super important but I would like to delete every second line from it - I have tried following this guide: [Delete every other line in notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735289/delete-every-other-line-in-notepad)

However I just can't get it to work, is the regex I am using ok? I am noob with regex

Find:

```
([^\n]*\n)[^\n]*\n
```

Replace with:

```
$1
```

No matter what I try (mouse position at the beginning, ctrl+a and Replace All) I just can't get it to work.  I appreciate any help.

I've put the regex into here: http://regexpal.com/ and if I remove the final \n it highlights the individual rows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you select *regular expression* for the *search mode*...

Also, you may want to [make that final newline optional](http://regex101.com/r/tR0zY9).  In the case that there are an even number of lines and you do not have a trailing newline, it won't remove the last line.

```
([^\n]*\n)[^\n]*\n?
```

---

**Update:**

See how [Windows handle new lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013034/does-windows-carriage-return-r-n-consist-of-two-characters-or-one-character) with `\r\n` instead of just `\n`.  Try [updating the expression](http://regex101.com/r/nZ9nK9) to take this into account:

```
([^\r\n]*[\r\n]+)[^\r\n]*[\r\n]*
```

---

**Final Update:**

Thanks to @zx81, I now know that N++ uses PCRE so `\R` can be used for unicode newline characters.  However `[^\R]` won't work (this looks for anything except `R` literally), so you will need to keep `[^\r\n]`.  This [can be simplified as](http://regex101.com/r/cH8tJ4):

```
([^\r\n]*\R)[^\r\n]*\R?
```

Comment: Yeah I have reg ex selected under search mode - I have tried your sample within notepad++ at it works...unfortunately if I implement it against my file it doesn't.  Just states 0 occurences was replaced.  The content per line varies but I assume (without understanding the expression - googling it now) it doesn't matter

Comment: No it shouldn't matter.  The original expression should've worked fine -- the main thing was the search mode.

Comment: Thought so - I've tried re-creating my text file and it just doesn't work...I'm using notepad++ 6.5.5 I assume thats pretty up-to-date? (updatin t now)

Comment: Yea, that came out 2 months ago according to their page. I'm on Linux and don't have Wine on this machine so I can't try it out in N++, but if you want to update your question with an uploaded screenshot of your find/replace window I can look for an issue.

Comment: I'll switch to Linux myself and see how I get on.  Weirdly, I tried copying and pasting my text into another new file and it worked first time....regex/replace was fine - just notepad++ being stupid?

Comment: @n34_panda actually seems like Windows being "stupid", see my update.

Comment: marked as answered - cheers! Decided to use my linux and sed to avoid it happening again.

Comment: +1 Sam, but since N++ uses PCRE, you can replace `[\r\n]` with `\R`, and `[^\r\n]` with `[^\R]` :)

Comment: Good catch @zx81, I didn't have N++ to test PCRE so I played it safe.

Comment: @Sam Yes, I was high when I wrote the `[^\R]`... :) `(?!\R).` works there but doesn't save any chars.

Comment: The entire `\r` thing is superfluous. The `\r` will be matched by the `[^\n]` part, so it will be either copied to the result, or thrown away with the `\n`. It wasn't actually an oversight in the linked answer, but rather a conscious improvement (since the original regex works with both line endings).