# Notepad++ backspace before word

Tags: notepad++

I have tons of addresses in a text file:

```
156-20 Riverside Drive W. Apt. 16c 
New York, NY 10032
```

And I want to convert each of them to be in a single line:

```
156-20 Riverside Drive W. Apt. 16c New York, NY 10032
```

Comment: Your addresses have multiple lines?

Comment: http://screenshu.com/static/uploads/temporary/v2/id/ve/er7ayn.jpg

Look SS. Yes, first line:156-20 Riverside Drive W. Apt. 16c 
secound line: New York, NY 10032
All must be on first line: 156-20 Riverside Drive W. Apt. 16c New York, NY 10032(like this)

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735289/delete-every-other-line-in-notepad)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression replace:

Find:

```
([0-9]+[^\n]+)\r\n([^\n]+)
```

Replace with:

```
\1 \2
```

Be careful to replace, make a backup before run replace.

[image]