# Selecting every other line in VS Code with regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a file where every line is duplicated (unfortunately).

```
My Name Is John
My Name Is John
I'm 30 years old
I'm 30 years old
New York is my home town
New York is my home town
```

I want to "revert" the duplication, in other words, select every other line and delete it.
Is there a way to do it using regex replacement in VS Code?

(Working on a mac, so Notepad++ solutions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735289/delete-every-other-line-in-notepad%20*here*) are irrelevant.
I know it's possible using bash, but I want to try to do it in VS Code)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this using Replace-All with regex. Find:

```
(.*)\n\1
```

Replace with:

```
$1\n
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks! Works great! Only it keeps an empty line.
So Finding this: `(.*)\n\1\n` and replacing with this `$1\n` does the trick.