# Delete odd numbered lines in text, skip blank lines

Tags: regex, text, notepad++

I have text of a poem that starts with the original language on odd numbered lines and a translation on even numbered lines.  I want to remove the original language odd lines.  I could use the [Notepad++ replace function with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735289/delete-every-other-line-in-notepad) `([^\n]*\n)[^\n]*\n` to remove every odd numbered line but when it reaches the blank lines between paragraphs, it switches to removing the translated lines and some of the blank lines also get removed.

How would I remove the odd lines while skipping and keeping the blank lines (it doesn't have to be done in Notepad++)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be:

```
^.+\R(.+)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oDVPcL/1)

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `.+\R` - Any 1+ characters upto any unicode newlince sequence;
- `(.+)` - Capture a 2nd line of 1+ characters in a capture group.

Replace with `\1`

Comment: I've been trying hard to understand why this works but I can't.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a small python script like this

```
lines = []
with open("sample.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if len(line) > 1:
            lines.append(line)

with open("sample.txt", "w") as f:
    for number, line in enumerate(lines):
        if not number % 2 == 0:
            f.write(line)
```

It checks if the line length is > 1 because newline counts as 1 for the length. It then appends the line to the list `lines` if there is any text in the line. It then checks if the line number is even or odd with `if not number & 2 == 0` (python indexing starts at 0 so 1 would actually be an even number.  Then it overrides the file with only even lines. If you want to delete even lines and keep odd lines, just remove the `not` in second to last line.

Comment: Thank you, for your help.  It was very kind of you.

Comment: no problem, I am new here so please upvote so I can get reputation to unlock features :)

Comment: I'd be glad to.